# conditional formatting on each date in a column of dates

Tags: excel, date, formatting, conditional-statements, formula

Struggling with this one a little.

I currently have a column (Column A) that has dates from cell 6 down to about cell 40. Each date is 7 days on from the previous one (This is a spreadsheet I used to check disc space on a weekly basis).

What I want to do, is for each cell, highlight it if it is previous or equal to today, and leave it unfilled if it is later than today.

I can get this working on one cell at a time by using conditional formatting based on a forumla. Here is the formula I tested on cell A6:

```
=A6<TODAY()
```

It works in that, if the date in A6 is previous to today, it fills in red, if it not, then it is left unformatted.
Is there a way to copy this conditional formatting down to each of the 33 other cells in this column?

I dont really want to have to do them one at a time, with a new formula for each.

Many thanks

Eds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the format painter. This will ONLY copy /paste the format (incl. conditional formatting).

Comment: I tested this at first and must have done it wrong as it didnt work. Can now say I have tried again and this works as expected, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By hand? Literally, copy and paste into the other cells. Excel should do a pretty intelligent job of updating row numbers in the formula for you. Even quicker, select the cell with the formula in. Drag the small dot in the bottom-right corner down to the last cell required, and it will do the lot in one sweep.

Comment: Sorry, i dont think I explained well enough, the dates are manually typed, not entered using a formula. What the above forumla is used for, is the conditional formatting to highlight the cell. If I copy the top date downwards, i dont think it copies the conditional formatting with it.

Comment: Sorry - I think I understand now. Paste Special from the Edit menu *might* help, but it might be one cell at a time even then... It might be worth taking a look at using VBA macros to achieve the result.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Tried copying, and then pasting special, but the only option is to merge conditional formatting, which means it still looks at the date in the original cell, so doesnt work quite how id like. I will carry on investigating.